# Stop all HTML5 audio/video with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

Trying to write a function that will pause all HTML5 audio and video.

I've got this far, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way about it?

```
function stopAll() {
var media = document.getElementsByClassName('media'),
    i = media.length;

while (i--) {
    media[i].pause();
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6AkC/

Comment: Looks good to me. You could just target the audio and video elements. Does it work as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>That works. In your fiddle, you have to make sure that the source tags are closed and that no wrap - in  is selected.</del>

The problem was really in your fiddle. You need to make sure that **no wrap - in head** is selected as the option on the upper left under Frameworks & Extensions. See the updated fiddle at @ http://jsfiddle.net/m6AkC/2/.

```
<audio class="media" id="audioplayer" controls>
<source src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/BlackBerry.mp4" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="audio/macdemarco.ogg" type="audio/ogg">Your browser does not support this audio format.</audio>
<video class="media" width="340" height="200" controls>
<source src="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/BlackBerry.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="stopAll()" id="next">Stop</a>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question and the only thing you did, was to suggest worse markup. Learn HTML please: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/source.html#source-tags | http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: @alexander-farkas - Thanks for pointing out the error. I had simply tried to fix the markup as jsfiddle had highlighted it as incorrect and I didn't realize that source tags were void tags.